# Influential factors setting the operation point of a bipolar transistor?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I do know why and where we should set the operation point of a transistor. We also learned calculations during lecture. However I do not know, what values do we change to set the Ib DC current. Are we changing the resistances in the system, or what else?

Comment: In many biassing arrangements, Ib sets itself. A more specific question might get a better answer.

Comment: my questio is basically wether we set the Ubc, Ib, Uce, or we set the arrangement by choosing the right resistances, and we just calculate the previously mentioned values.

Comment: I think that depends on the arrangement.  So I'm going to be more specific about being more specific. Pick one bias scheme, add its schematic to the question, and ask questions about the bits you don't understand.

Comment: Under bias scheme you mean something like common emitter bipolar transistor?

Comment: Yes. But there are at least two common approaches to biassing a common emitter transistor., with different characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one way to bias a BJT.  Generally it is good for some DC feedback to stabilize the bias point so that it varies little for transistor gain over a reasonable range.  A classic example is resistor from collector to base with another resistor from base to ground for NPN.

The bias values are likely adjusted by resistances.  However, to say you change the bias by "changing the resistances" may often be correct but is oversimplifying things to the point of uselessness.

Answer (score 0):

You typically bias a transistor to optimize some conflicting, variable, and perhaps unclear goals:

1: To minimize wasted power (current)
2: To allow the AC component of a signal (added to the DC bias) to not cause the total signal to cross zero (e.g. switch off the device), or overload the device.
3: To make the AC component of the signal small enough relative to the DC component that the device operates with sufficient linearity (e.g. Class A audio pre amp).
4: To get the highest gain from the device -- generally higher bias currents will have higher gain).
5: To get the highest frequency performance -- generally at higher bias currents.
6: To minimize performance changes with shifts in other parameters (different transistor samples, temperature, supply voltage, resistances, loads, inputs etc.)